# Can't install Hyper-V Remote Management Console

Tags: windows-vista, hyper-v

**Solved!**

I'm trying to remotely manage a Hyper-V server from my desktop PC. Following [these](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/vista/remotely-manage-a-microsoft-hyper-v-server-from-a-windows-vista-client/) instructions, I've downloaded the Hyper-V Remote Management Update for Windows Vista for x64-based Systems (KB952627). When I attempt to install it, I get the error "This update does not apply to your system."

I'm running Windows Vista SP2, 64-bit.

Edit:
I've also tried Update for Windows Vista Service Pack 2 Management Tools for Hyper-V for x64-based Systems (KB970203), to the same results.

**Solved!**
I found this update: http://www.microsoftpost.com/microsoft-download/update-for-windows-vista-for-x64-based-systems-kb952627/
It worked.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and after 48 hours you can mark it as accepted. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: I have no idea why that didn't occur to me. I've done it before. Must be the cold medication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this update: http://www.microsoftpost.com/microsoft-download/update-for-windows-vista-for-x64-based-systems-kb952627/ It worked.